# Change Text in Admin Panel

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-admin

How can I change the text `Posts` to `News` ? I am developing a Plugin. I am working with Custom Post Types.

Comment: Have you set all the labels, as documented? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters, which links to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/#description

Comment: please use the built in image upload functionality, don't link to a 3rd party site for screenshots. I've edited it out, you can use the Edit link to re-add your screenshot using the image button in the toolbar